# A Digitigrade Human

Tags: biology, evolution, humans

We humans are plantigrades.  That means our feet rest flat on the ground.  We have large, bony heels to make sure that our flat feet stay supported under our vertical legs.

But among mammals is another popular method of support--digitigrade, meaning that the animal walks on its digits, or toes, and keeps the rest of its feet off the ground.  Our closest picture of a digitigrade human is a ballerina:

[image]

The only problem is that even the most experienced ballerinas can't keep to the tips of their toes for long.  But what if they could?  The most obvious thing would be to reduce or eliminate the heel, as a large ball of bone would not be necessary if the majority of the foot is off the ground.  What advantages would standing on tiptoe bring to the human species as opposed to putting the feet completely flat on the ground?

Comment: A ballerina is not walking like a digitigrade. A person walking like a digitigrade would simply be someone walking like they're wearing heels, without actually wearing the heels - in other words, their toes are still flat along the ground. The picture you have posted, claiming it as a digitigrade example, is equivalent to an actual digitigrade walking on the tips of their claws, not their toes.

Comment: "A digitigrade...is an animal that stands or walks on its digits, or toes."

Comment: If you [search for the word "digitigrade"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=digitigrade+is%3Aquestion), you'll find this kind of question has been asked many times and in many ways before.

Comment: None of which focused on HUMANS but instead human-OIDS.  Two different things.

Comment: The picture you have posted is of a human walking on the tips of its toes, not on its toes. Big difference.

Comment: It's still digits.

Answer (score 0):

> What advantages would standing on tiptoe bring to the human species as opposed to putting the feet completely flat on the ground?

None.

If we stay bipedal then there is no advantage that outweighs the many disadvantages in todays World.

One small advantage is we may have horny hoof type feet and not require shoes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/43714)

Comment: It answers the question directly

Comment: it would answer better if you could expand it a bit more.

Comment: make up your mind mate, first it doesn't, now it does but not the way you want...

Comment: The prefilled review lines do not give room to literary attempts. What you see is the standard line for " this a comment, not an answer"

Comment: @L.Dutch You could write a normal comment from the review and then choose "no comment needed" after clicking on "recommend deletion". That may make it clearer in cases where the canned comments do not quite fit the situation you are reviewing.